# Require Weblogic Stop All Managed Servers WLST Script which are in Running state except AdminServer

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, weblogic12c, wlst

My requirement is to stop all servers in a weblogic domain which are in running state except AdminServer. I have got similar one and modified, but getting syntax error while executing. Could someone please look at it and help me out ?

```
import sys
import re
import getopt

def connectt():
    connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ADMINURL)

def getdomainstatus():
    servers=cmo.getServers()
    print "-------------------------------------------------------"
    print "\t"+cmo.getName()+" domain current status"
    print "-------------------------------------------------------"
    for server in servers:
            status=state(server.getName(),server.getType())
    print "-------------------------------------------------------"     

# Stop the servers which are Running except AdminServer
def stopmanagedservers():
        servers=cmo.getServers()
    domainRuntime()
    for server in servers:
        if server.getName() != 'AdminServer':
        bean="/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/"+server.getName()
        serverbean=getMBean(bean)
        if serverbean.getState() in ("RUNNING"):
            print "Stopping the servers which are in RUNNING status"
            print "Stopping the Server ",server.getName()
            shutdown(server.getName(),server.getType())

    serverConfig()
.
.
.
.

connectt()
getdomainstatus();
stopmanagedservers();
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: It is very difficult without error we cannot help you Vignesh